# ¿Se puede cambiar el directorio de guardado?

Tags: python

Mi duda es si al guradar una matriz numpy como imagen de la forma que adjunto se puede establecer el directorio de guardado o tiene que ser obligatoriamente el mismo que el archivo .py:

```
imcv2 = Image.fromarray(val_fin)
imcv2 = imcv2.convert('I;16')
imcv2.save("Imagen.TIFF")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, efectivamente puedes hacerlo [referencia](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-and-saving-images-in-python-ba5a1f5058fb?gi=99acd8b98f99), solo es de colocar la ruta que deseas guardar el documento

```
imcv2.save(r'\dogs-v-cats\dog.1.png')
```

Indicando donde deseas guardarlo, ten en cuenta que dejar rutas quemadas puede afectar alguna funcionalidad en un futuro, asegurate de que si lo haces, es porque no hay necesidad de cambiarla luego

@abulafia dice 'Mejor no usar `\` como separador de rutas, pues específico de Windows y puede dar problemas en Linux. Usar `/` en cambio es aceptado en ambos.' y tiene razón, depende de ti que prefieres

Comment: Mejor no usar \ como separador de rutas, pues específico de Windows y puede dar problemas en Linux. Usar `/` en cambio es aceptado en ambos.

Comment: Gracias, y alguna manera de que te salga de forma visual para que el usuario pueda elegir dicho directorio?

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez Puedes buscar OpenDialogFile en python, yo encontré este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8WDvrjPt0M